# Is there a Url-redirect Service without Hash?

Tags: url, redirect, service, url-shortener

Iam looking for a URL redirect Service without generating hashes. Just simple like "go.to/?url=google.com".

Because i dont want to generate hashes before and The host detection will ban my Host/IP maybe.
 Or is there a shortener-Service where i can generate the hashes by myself without any api request like it was possible with The  delicio.us API years ago?

Comment: What's the point of such redirect? Why would someone use "go.to/?url=google.com" if he can use "google.com" without any redirect? That's nonsense.

Comment: Because of The performance of the hash-api, and The Referer ip detection

Comment: Read my comment once more and better, please. My question is why should you use any redirect at all? Why should I use "go.to/?url=google.com" instead of directly "google.com"? That doesn't make a sense.

Comment: Also time taken by computing a hash and "detection of referer's IP" (this is nonsense, referer's IP is sent in HTTP request, so you don't have to "detect" anything) is orders of magnitude shorter than time taken by a HTTP request (network roundtrip). So time taken by a request will be roughly the same with or without hash computation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a Service which redirect without detecting my Host/Ip:

http://nullrefer.com/?http:/google.com